# phonegap - android market

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

i have an application build with phonegap and i need to open the market after the user touch a button in an alert dialog...can i do this? how?

I see on google that is possibile with a link in the page but i need this in the dialog...

this is my dialog:

```
function onConfirm(button) {
        if(button == 1)
            alert('market');
    }


function showPrimoAvvio() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Se ti piace questa app ti chiediamo di lasciare un voto e un commento positivo nel market per aiutarci a sviluppare applicazioni sempre migliori!!',  // message
        onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        'Votami!',            // title
        'Vota,Prosegui'          // buttonLabels
    );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onConfirm method once you've checked that the button == 1 you can just set:

```
document.location.href="market://search?q=google"
```

for instance to do a search on the Android market for apps by Google. To link to a specific app you would do:

```
document.location.href="market://details?id=com.example.admob.lunarlander"
```

where com.example.admob.lunarlander is the package name of your application.

Comment: thaks! this is exactly what i need!

Answer (score 0):

You can honestly just open the market.android.com url, and the user will be able to select "open with market".

Try it by going to the browser and entering the URL! It may be a work around until you can figure out how to bypass that and go straight to the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" native function, here's a good post about it:

[Open the android market from an app](http://samstewartapps.com/blog/2010/10/12/open-the-android-market-from-an-app/)